# Low-poly model artifacts

Tags: modeling

I am very new to modeling, and I have been modeling most of the time with subdivison surfaces, which have been working very well. But then when I tried to model a low-poly model, it tended to look very unclean and had a lot of artifacts.

[image]
[image]

I saw a video where someone was modeling something similar, and his model looks very clean compared to mine, and I am not sure why.

Are there things to look out for when doing low-poly quad modeling?

[image]

[link to .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28554)

Comment: Which parts of your model are "unclean and have lots of artifacts"? Can you post a picture with those parts highlighted?

Comment: Also, are you trying to get the blade edge to have a nice sharp edge to it, but the other sides be rounded?

Comment: Are you hoping to reduce the number of polygons and still keep the same shape?

Comment: No, I wanted a clean mesh with sharp edges. I solved it by using the EdgeSplit modifier.